# No puedo mostrar la imagen tomada con la camara en un ImageView!

Tags: android-studio, cámara, android-imageview

**Estoy tratando de capturar una foto y mostrarla en un ImageView, para despues enviarla por WebService a un servidor externo**

El problema lo tengo al momento de mostrar la imageview, No me muestra nada.
Pero el nombre de la imagen si me lo muestra en un Edittext, y tambien se guarda en la tarjeta de memoria

les dejo mi Activity.java

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Modificar extends AppCompatActivity {

    String correo,correo1,correo2;
    String pass;
    Session session = null;
    String mensaje;
    String imageName;

    String status;
    TextView tvnombre,
            tvfolio,
            tvasunto,
            tvfecha,
            tvdireccion,
            tvtelefono,
            tvlugar,
            tvestado;
    EditText txobservaciones, nombreImagen;
    Button actualizar, borrar, turnar;
    ImageView imagen;

    RadioButton activo,pendiente,concluido,noprocede;
    RadioGroup grupo;
    Spinner spin;
    ProgressDialog pdialog = null;

    private Uri output;
    private String foto;
    private File file;
    private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "MyPictureApp/";
    private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "PictureApp";

    private final int PHOTO_CODE = 200;
    private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 300;
    private RelativeLayout mRlView;
    private String mPath;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String URL = "http://lahuerta.gob.mx/WebService/actualizar.php";
    private StringRequest request;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modificar);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        ctx=this;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String nombre = intent.getStringExtra("nombre");
        final String folio = intent.getStringExtra("folio");
        String asunto = intent.getStringExtra("asunto");
        String fecha = intent.getStringExtra("fecha");
        String direccion = intent.getStringExtra("direccion");
        String telefono = intent.getStringExtra("telefono");
        String lugar = intent.getStringExtra("lugar");
        final String estado = intent.getStringExtra("estado");
        final String observaciones = intent.getStringExtra("observaciones");

        tvnombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvnombre);
        tvasunto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvasunto);
        tvfolio = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfolio);
        tvfecha = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfecha);
        tvdireccion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdireccion);
        tvestado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvestado);
        tvtelefono = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtelefono);
        tvlugar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvlugar);
        txobservaciones = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txobservaciones);
        actualizar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmodificar);
        borrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnborrar);
        turnar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnturnar);
        activo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioActivo);
        pendiente = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioPendiente);
        concluido = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioConcluido);
        noprocede = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioNoprocede);
        grupo = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spturnar);
        nombreImagen = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edimagen);
        imagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mRlView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_modificar);


        tvnombre.setText(nombre);
        tvasunto.setText(asunto);
        String nFolio = folio;
        tvfolio.setText("Folio: "+folio);
        tvfecha.setText(fecha);
        tvdireccion.setText(direccion);
        tvtelefono.setText(telefono);
        tvlugar.setText(lugar);
        tvestado.setText(estado);
        txobservaciones.setText(observaciones);     

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

//Aqui uso el floatingbutton para las acciones de captura

            fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   showOptions();
                }
            });


        }

//Aqui doy a elegir la opcion de Camara o Galeria

    private void showOptions(){
            final CharSequence[] option = {"Tomar foto", "Elegir de galeria", "Cancelar"};
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Modificar.this);
            builder.setTitle("Eleige una opción");
            builder.setItems(option, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(option[which] == "Tomar foto"){
                        getCamara();
                    }else if(option[which] == "Elegir de galeria"){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }else {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

//Aqui creo el directorio y mando a llamar la camara

        private void getCamara(){
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

            if(!isDirectoryCreated)
                isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

            if(isDirectoryCreated){
                Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

                mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                        + File.separator + imageName;

                File newFile = new File(mPath);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
                startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
            }

//Aqui recivo la respuesta y trato de mostrar la imagen en un ImageView

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                switch (requestCode){
                    case PHOTO_CODE:
                        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                                new String[]{mPath}, null,
                                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                                    }
                                });

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                        imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                        break;
                    case SELECT_PICTURE:
                        Uri path = data.getData();
                        imagen.setImageURI(path);
                        nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: hola.. podrias por lo menos señalar en donde de todo ese codigo esta o sospechas que esta el error?

Comment: no me muestra ningun error.. la amplicacion corre bien, es por eso mi duda.. Tengo todos los permisos.

Comment: y probaste con una imagen estatica, que sabes que ya existe?

Comment: tengo esta opcion en donde puedo escoger la imagen desde la galeria.. Pero tampoco me muestra la imagen..   `case SELECT_PICTURE:
                        Uri path = data.getData();
                        imagen.setImageURI(path);
                        nombreImagen.setText(imageName);
                        break;`

Comment: estonces tu problema no es con la camara.. es mostrando una imagen cualquiera...

Comment: ya encontre el problema... Le baje la resolucion al tomar la foto, y a hora si me la muestra... sabes de alguna forma de bajar la resolucion en codigo, sin que el usuario tenga que moverle a las cofiguraciones de la camara?..